# Curl error Protocol "" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping, rvest

In Rvest I get this error when I try to submit forms what is the error about

```
> search <- html_form(read_html("http://www.google.com"))[[1]]
> filledform<-set_values(search, q = "Tripadvisor")
> filledform
<form> 'f' (GET /search)
  <input hidden> 'ie': ISO-8859-1
  <input hidden> 'hl': sw-KE
  <input hidden> 'source': hp
  <input hidden> 'biw': 
  <input hidden> 'bih': 
  <input text> 'q': Tripadvisor
  <input submit> 'btnG': Tafuta na Google
  <input submit> 'btnI': Najisikia Nina Bahati
  <input hidden> 'iflsig': AINFCbYAAAAAXwh1Gb4SG4gwHsk84hsdtwWV95dbxZLy
  <input hidden> 'gbv': 1
> submit_form(search,filledform,submit = "btnG")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Protocol "" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Comment: It looks like you need to make that form action an absolute url somehow. Maybe post an issue on their github page.

Comment: I am getting the error for all websites.  I reproduced it with a google search, do you know how to write the absolute URL for this case

Comment: yeah. it's https://www.google.com/search - actually, the http in your url might be the problem because it will trigger redirects which rvest doesn't seem to handle properly.